# Javascript show/hide links not working

Tags: javascript, svg

[Click on Ike's](http://zadias.me/SVG/SVG2/Eisenhower/PresParkEisenhower.html) and you'll notice a div appear below the map. Try to click on the link. It's not working.

I'm using this to show/hide the div's on click

```
function ikesClick() {
            filler.style.display='none';
            FrontDeskDesc.style.display='none'; 
            LoungeDesc.style.display='none';    
            StudyDesc.style.display='none'; 
            IkesDesc.style.display='inline';    
        };
```

If you view the page source, you can see the entirety of the Javascript there.

**My question is, what do I do to make the link clickable?**

I'm almost certain this is happening because of the way it's displaying none/inline.

You can observe the HTML here:

```
<section id="roomInfo">
    <section id="filler" style="display:inline">
    Hover over or select a colored area for details about individual rooms and locations in the library.
    </section>
    <section id="IkesDesc" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Ike's - Late Night Diner</h1>
    <p>
    In the hub of President’s Park, Ike’s provides a late night dining option.  Visit <a href="dining.gmu.edu">dining.gmu.edu</a> for hours of operation.
    </p>
    <img src="Ikes.JPG" style="max-width:500px; width:100%;" alt="Ike's Facade" />
    </section>
    <section id = "FrontDeskDesc" style="display:none;">
    Get your temporary keys and stuff here!
    </section>
    <section id ="LoungeDesc" style="display:none;">
    loungin'
    </section>
    <section id ="StudyDesc" style="display:none;">
    Studying for finals yo
    </section>
</section><!--end room info-->
```

The problem persists under the section "IkesDesc" where the link to dining.gmu.edu is.

Comment: that it is not jquery mate ;)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The link isn't clickable because the <svg id="svg"> element is covering the <svg id="roomInfo"> element.  
You can see this using Chrome you right click on the link and press "Inspect Element", you'll notice the source code pops open and the <svg id="svg"> tag (or some child of it) is highlighted.

I don't know svg well enough to know the solution, if it's a height property issue, or something to do with class="active".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your link is incomplete:

```
<a href="dining.gmu.edu">dining.gmu.edu</a>
```

So this should be something like:

```
<a href="https://gmu.sodexomyway.com/home.xhtml">dining.gmu.edu</a>
```

Also, since you have jQuery already running on the page, you might want to simplify your code to:

```
$("#Ikes").click(function() {

  $(".objects").hide();
  $(this).show();

});
```

Where `Ikes` is the `id` of the clickable `img` and `.objects` is the class of all the clickable images.

Also, I saw that it is not possible to click `Ikes` in FireFox. So you might want to look into that as well.

### UPDATE

What seems to be causing the problem is your layout:

you use `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` throughout whereas this is quite dangerous when 'spawning' divs.

For example:

```
#svg {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: -55px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#roomInfo {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    margin-top: 75%;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, you seem to position some elements as if they have position absolute whereas they actually are placed relative.

I advice you to make the total layout relative such that it is responsive and can handle things as smaller screens and the spawning of divs.

I helped you a bit in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CxwQ/1/), but I'll leave the rest for you.

Also, look at my jQuery code which basically reduces [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/x38EV/) to the jQuery used in my jsFiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#area1").click(function() {
       $(".extra").hide();
       $("#IkesDesc").show();
    });

    $("#area2").click(function() {
       $(".extra").hide();
       $("#FrontDeskDesc").show();
    });

    $("#area3").click(function() {
       $(".extra").hide();
       $("#LoungeDesc").show();
    });

    $("#area4").click(function() {
       $(".extra").hide();
       $("#StudyDesc").show();
    });
});
```

I made the example working so you can copy/paste as you please.

Also, I added the following:

```
var position = $("#IkesDesc").position();
   scroll(0,position.top);
```

This is a really cool trick that will scroll to the div that just appeared such that the user actually notices something changed (I kind of miss that in your current site).

You can check it as a working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2CxwQ/2/).

I hope that helped you out!

Good luck!

Comment: Changing the link isn't the problem; though it probably is a good idea.  But you can't even highlight text or right click the image, in that section.

Comment: My understanding is the idea is to find the answer to the question, and then post your answer, not the other way around; as of yet, this doesn't answer the question, hence the downvote.  I'll remove the downvote if this becomes an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to simplify my code the way you've mentioned, but that just makes it not work at all.. Retsam described my problem perfectly, I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Also, I've only tested this in Chrome and my Android device, thanks for the heads up, I'll check out the issues with firefox. **EDIT** I'm  on my work computer and it has the latest version of firefox and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2533212: I found some improvements for your code. Check the update above.

Comment: @Retsam: I understand your reasoning and maybe I should have fully finished my answer before posting. Thank you for removing.